# How to add one more column in jquery datatable which is not present in the json response

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, datatables

I'm using one api in which the response is coming in two columns but in one column there are many parameters, I need to decode one column and want to show in different columns.

Column name coming from api timestamp, dataFrame, I need to show in 3 columns timestamp, oil temperature and winding temperature. I need to add one more column in datatable to show the values in the datatable.
sample json data

```
[{
        "timestamp": "2018-07-21T07:56:23.838Z",
        "dataFrame": "HA=="
    },
    {
        "timestamp": "2018-07-21T08:16:23.902Z",
        "dataFrame": "HA=="
    }
]
```

output
[image]

Expected Output

Timestamp, Oil Temp, winding temp in 3 separate columns

code

```
 <script>
        window.onload = getddata();
        function getddata() {
            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    var Readings = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
                    //jquery data table - start
                    $(document).ready(function () {
                        $('#example').DataTable({
                            columnDefs: [{
                                "targets": 1,
                                "render": function (data, type, row, meta) {
                                 var hexvalue =base64toHEX(data);
                                 var deviceid= hexToDec(hexvalue.substr(1,1));
                                 var oil_temp= hexToDec(hexvalue.substr(2,2));
                                 var winding_temp= hexToDec(hexvalue.substr(4,2));

                                 return 'oil temp: ' + oil_temp + ', Winding Temp: ' + winding_temp + ' ;
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "targets": 0,
                                "render": function (data, type, row, meta) {
                                var updDate=  UtcToIst(data).toLocaleDateString();
                                var updTime=  UtcToIst(data).toLocaleTimeString();
                                var updDateTime=updDate + ", " + updTime;
                                return  updDateTime ;
                            }
                            }



            }


                            ],


                            data: Readings,
                            columns: [{
                                "data": "timestamp"
                            }, {
                                "data": "dataFrame"
                            }
                          ]


                        });
                    });
                    //data table code -close

                }
            };
            xmlhttp.open("GET", "https://.., true);
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic a2VybmV");
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "Application/json");
            xmlhttp.send();

        }


    </script>
```

Comment: It would be nice to see a sample of the `Readings` JSON.

Comment: i have updated the json response in my question. can u check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me the code is a little bit overcomplicated. Why not just reuse `dataFrame` over multiple `columns`? Perhaps I misunderstand the question ...

```js
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
   data: sampleReadings,
   columns: [
     { data: 'timestamp', title: 'timestamp',
       render: function(data) {
         return data
         /* dont know what UtcToIst is
         var updDate=  UtcToIst(data).toLocaleDateString();
         var updTime=  UtcToIst(data).toLocaleTimeString();
         var updDateTime=updDate + ", " + updTime;
         return  updDateTime ;
         */
       }
     },
     { data: 'dataFrame', title: 'deviceid',
       render: function(data) {
         var hexvalue = base64toHEX(data);
         return hexToDec(hexvalue.substr(1,1));
       }
     },
     { data: 'dataFrame', title: 'Oil temp',
       render: function(data) {
         var hexvalue = base64toHEX(data);
         return hexToDec(hexvalue.substr(2,2));
       }
     },
     { data: 'dataFrame', title: 'Winding temp',
       render: function(data) {
         var hexvalue = base64toHEX(data);
         return hexToDec(hexvalue.substr(4,2));
       }
     },
     //I guess there is more data hidden in dataFrame
     //You can almost copy paste new columns here
   ]
})
```

If you have 10.000 records it would be a good idea to cache the output from `base64toHEX`.

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/fn0yL361/**

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add a new column and render related value. Please update the data tables column.
https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.name

```
 {  columnDefs: [{
                    "targets": 2,
                    "name": "winding temp",
                    "render": function (data, type, row, meta) {
                     var hexvalue =base64toHEX(data);
                     var deviceid= hexToDec(hexvalue.substr(1,1));
                     var oil_temp= hexToDec(hexvalue.substr(2,2));
                     var winding_temp= hexToDec(hexvalue.substr(4,2));

                     return 'Winding Temp: ' + winding_temp  ;
                    }
                },{
                    "targets": 1,
                    "name": "Oil temp",
                    "render": function (data, type, row, meta) {
                     var hexvalue =base64toHEX(data);
                     var deviceid= hexToDec(hexvalue.substr(1,1));
                     var oil_temp= hexToDec(hexvalue.substr(2,2));
                     var winding_temp= hexToDec(hexvalue.substr(4,2));

                     return 'oil temp: ' + oil_temp ;
                    }
                },
                {
                    "targets": 0,
                      "name" : "Timestamp",
                    "render": function (data, type, row, meta) {
                    var updDate=  UtcToIst(data).toLocaleDateString();
                    var updTime=  UtcToIst(data).toLocaleTimeString();
                    var updDateTime=updDate + ", " + updTime;
                    return  updDateTime ;
                }
                }
                ],
                data: Readings,
                columns: [{
                    "data": "timestamp"
                }, {
                    "data": "dataFrame"
                },
                  {
                    "data": "dataFrame"
                }
              ]
```

Comment: getting error in name property ,   "name: "winding temp",error- (local function)(data: any, type: any, row: any, meta: any): string

Comment: while adding the dataFrame column twice, getting error, {
                                "data": "dataFrame"
                            }, gettign error

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example, because there are spaces in Name so need some extra code to get field:

```
var str = "{timestamp: 'xxx', dataFrame: 'Old Time: xx,  winding Time: yyyy, Ambient Time: zzzz'}";
var objOrg = JSON.parse(str);

var newJSon = [{}];
foreach (var itm in objOrg)
{ 
   var new3Fields = itm.dataFrame;
   var arr = new3Fields.split(',')
   var newItem = {};

   newItem.timestamp = itm.timestamp;
   newItem.OldTime = JSON.parse(arr[0]).['Old Time'];
   newItem.WindingTime = JSON.parse(arr[1]).['winding Time'];
   newItem.AmbientTime = JSON.parse(arr[2]).['Ambient Time'];

   newJSon += newItem;
}
newJSon  <--- This is a list with 4 columns
```

Comment: I didnt knew javascript has a `foreach` loop type :)

Comment: Yeah, it is just a prototype ;)